# One word for simplicity, expressiveness, and error avoidance?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

Is there a good word to describe all three of them? Currently, I'm writing my thesis, and it's about designing an API. So one of my goals is to achieve all of these: simplicity, expressiveness and error avoidance. Meaning, that the API should be self-explanatory, be expressive and help the programmer to produce less errors. Any ideas how to combine all of these in one word?

Comment: Any word that would even come close would favor one of the concepts while soft-pedaling the others. Why can't you use all three? Or coin a new word (or acronym) and define its meaning as those three things.

Comment: I don't think there is a single word that isn't uber-general (like "good" or "usable").  Aren't these concepts important enough to call out?

Answer (score 1):

"intuitive" - as in this [definition](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia_term/0,1233,t=intuitive+software&i=58977,00.asp) of intuitive software:

> Application programs that have a friendly interface and work like
>   users would expect. Menu functions are available in a logical order
>   that one finds natural. The most common functions are presented in one
>   menu or are located at the top of the menu list rather than being
>   buried in rigid hierarchies that make sense only to the programmer who
>   wrote the program. In other words, extremely rare software!

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to suppose that an *intuitive* user interface design would *help the programmer to produce less errors*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I suppose if it were intuitive enough to auto-correct certain user errors such as removing extra spaces or giving an error message if a phone number doesn't have enough digits, for example.  My software programmers have added that kind of intuitive "intelligence" to our product.

Comment: Ah. I see your point. But in practice, code that's smart enough to make things easier for *users* usually has to be much more complex (and thus error-prone) than code which forces the user to adapt to the way the software works. I once wrote a "foundry defects analysis" system for international use. All the users *could* have understood English well enough to use it, but they paid extra for me to code it using user-maintained "language packs" (luckily, I was a shit-hot coder, so I was able to deal with the extra errors caused by the extra complexity, and still get paid by a happy customer! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, awesome! You're right -there's always bound to be a trade-off.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to demean Robusto's idea to “coin a new word (or acronym) and define its meaning as those three things”, but suggest that you instead re-purpose an existing word, for example 
*[robust](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/robust#Adjective)*, which has several suitable senses:

> straightforward, not given to or confused by uncertainty or subtlety;
>   Resistant or impervious to failure regardless of user input or unexpected conditions.

Here are some other candidates:

> • *[balanced](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/balanced)*, in its senses of “having weight evenly distributed”, “mentally and emotionally stable”, and “presenting opposing points of view fairly and without bias”
>   • *[smooth](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smooth#Adjective)*, particularly in its sense “Without difficulty, problems, or unexpected consequences or incidents” but also in the senses “suave; sophisticated” and  “natural; unconstrained”
>   • *[elegant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elegant#Adjective)* (“Characterised by minimalism and intuitiveness while preserving exactness and precision”),
>   • *[friendly](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/friendly#Adjective)* (“Having an easy relationship with something, as in user-friendly etc”),
>   • *[usable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/usable#Adjective)*
>   • *[ergonomic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ergonomic#Adjective)*

For example, you might define a *usability score*, or an *elegance score* for an API, based on a weighted sum of its scores against your three main criteria.

Answer (score 1):

The word "succinct" comes to my mind, 
although it doesn't really denote 
"error free."  Still, it does convey
the ideas of brevity, pithiness (i.e.,
meaningful preciseness), and a lack of
fluff or unnecessary wordiness.